# properties file resides outside of the java app throws fFileNotFoundException

Tags: java, configuration-files

For some reason i have to place my `*.properties` files outside of java app. When the file `km.properties` resides in `java/src/resources/km.properties` the code reads the file but when i place  the same file in `C:\Users\abc\Desktop\km.properties`
it throws

```
Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: property file 'C:\Users\abc\Desktop\km.properties' not found in the classpath
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ir.Constants.<init>(Constants.java:44)
    at com.Constants.main(Constants.java:64)
```

here is my code

```
public class Constants {
    public Constants(){
        System.out.println(System.getenv("km_config"));
        try {
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            String propFileName = System.getenv("km_config");

            inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);

            if (inputStream != null) {
                prop.load(inputStream);
            } else {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
        } finally {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Constants c = new Constants();

         System.out.println(Constants.DB_PATH1);
         System.out.println(Constants.GIT_REPO_PATH);
         System.out.println(Constants.GIT_MAIN_BRANCH_NAME);
         System.out.println(Constants.TAGGER_PATH);
    }
```

`Constants.java:44` is 
                inputStream.close();

`Constants.java:64` is
        Constants c = new Constants();

please help me i need to place `km.properies` file any where outside of the java app

command results in

```
echo %km_config%

C:\Users\abc\Desktop\km.properties
```

Comment: km_config is system variable. Could you post value of this variable?

Comment: echo %km_config% results in C:\Users\abc\Desktop\km.properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API `ClassLoader::getResourceAsStream(String)` has a search path which is the classpath. Actually **you are right** that the configuration file should not be bundled with your .class files and read from the filesystem of the target machine instead.

Thus your API call becomes:

```
Properties conf = new Properties();
conf.load(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(file)));
```

<sub>Note: I did not specify a charset for converting the stream of bytes to a stream of character because I want the JVM to pick whatever character is the default for the system.</sub>

For testing I suggest you:

- put the configuration file in a known location out of the sources (the Desktop) or anyway ignored by the version control system
- pass the value as a system property (like `-Dfile=C:\Users\me\Desktop\km.properties`)